# Changing dfs0 time axis from equidistant to non-equidistant

Tags: mikeio

In order to use dfs0 in operational mode (in MIKE Operations), we need to convert a set of dfs0 with hourly data with an equidistant time axis to non-equidistant time axis.

I tried to load the dfs0 in a dataframe and re-write it but because the dataset is hourly when using dfs.write() the equidistant time axis is automatically used and I can't seem to find a way to manually force non-equidistant without altering the `DatetimeIndex`.

Thanks!

Comment: First time I heard about someone going from equidistant to non-equidistant, it is usually the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I got some help on the way and figured out that I can set the dataframe `index.freq` to `None` in order to create a non-equidistant dfs0 from a regular-interval dataset:

```
df.index.freq = None
```

My output dfs0 then has a non-equidistant calendar.